# How to extract the values of a .wav file

Tags: python, c, wav

i'm trying very hard to find a simple answer to an otherwise (i believe at least) very easy question. So i have let's say a .wav file of 16 bit, 44100 hz, stereo and i want to extract some of the 16 bits values from the file and see their actual values in a format that makes sense.I don't know if are signed or unsigned or float or anything else but at the end i want to have printed the value that means something.I have read that the first 44 bytes are irrelevant things so i want to have access to the values after these till the end. Secondly i want simply modify a value and save it to another .wav file.These things is best to do in c or python because are the only languages that i know. Thank you!

Comment: I would use something like the sounddevice library

Comment: My first two hits for Google `read .wav with python` are  https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html and https://stackoverflow.com/q/2060628/7010554. Maybe this could be a starting point?

Comment: Those first 44 bytes aren't samples, but they are things like number of channels, number of samples per second, etc.: not at all irrelevant, and not always exactly 44 bytes. WAV files are a subset of RIFF files. The Wikipedia articles on both formats are pretty good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a page asking almost the same question here with almost all the code written here:

[Extract amplitude array from a wav File using JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39313634/extract-amplitude-array-from-a-wav-file-using-java)

:-D

Comment: I accept your answer although refers to java and not in C, thank you